# float numbers in bash shell script

Tags: bash, floating-point

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Division in script and floating-point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12147040/division-in-script-and-floating-point)

```
Mismatch  Percentage: $((( 100 * $TEST2 ) / $TEST1))
```

I am trying to get float number from above code. I am using bash shell script. But the above code is not giving me float numbers. I guess bash does not support floating numbers

Comment: You can use `echo "Mismatch Percentage: $(echo "100*$TEST2/$TEST1" | bc -l)"`

Comment: What is the question here?  Did you try Googling for `BASH floating point numbers?` for work arounds?  `bc` is a good tool to know, and it thrives on floating point numbers.

Comment: Thanks guys, that worked. Can anyone post the solution so that I can accept the answer here?

Comment: Use korn shell 93 instead, that supports floating-point

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shameless steal from VaughnCato:

```
echo "Mismatch Percentage: $(echo "100*$TEST2/$TEST1" | bc -l)"
```

Answer (score 1):

I have defined a function in `~./bashrc`

```
function bashCalc ()
{
    bc <<< "scale=6;$1";
}
```

Now you can always use in your (sub)shell:

```
Mismatch Percentage: $(bashCalc (100*$TEST2)/$TEST1 )
```

See also: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/40786/how-can-i-do-command-line-integer-float-calculations-in-bash-or-any-language