# Floating point results in Bash integer division

Tags: bash, bc

I have a backup script on my server which does cron jobs of backups, and sends me a summary of  files backed up, including the size of the new backup file. As part of the script, I'd like to divide the final size of the file by (1024^3) to get the file size in GB, from the file size in bytes.

Since bash does not have floating point calculation, I am trying to use pipes to bc to get the result, however I'm getting stumped on basic examples.

I tried to get the value of Pi to a scale, however,

even though the following works:

```
~ #bc -l
bc 1.06.95
Copyright 1991-1994, 1997, 1998, 2000, 2004, 2006 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
For details type `warranty'.
4/3
1.33333333333333333333
22/7
3.14285714285714285714
q
0
quit
```

A non interactive version does not work:

```
#echo $(( 22/7 )) | bc
3
```

This works:

```
#echo '22/7' | bc -l
3.14285714285714285714
```

But I need to use variables. So it doesnt help that the following does not work:

```
#a=22 ; b=7
#echo $(( a/b )) | bc -l
3
```

I'm obviously missing something in the syntax for using variables in Bash, and could use with some 'pointers' on what I've misunderstood.

As DigitalRoss said, I can use the following:

```
#echo $a / $b | bc -l
3.14285714285714285714
```

However I cant use complex expressions like:

```
#echo $a / (( $b-34 )) | bc -l
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
#echo $a / (( b-34 )) | bc -l
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
#echo $a / (( b-34 )) | bc -l
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

Can someone give me a working correct syntax for getting floating point results with complicated arithmetic expresssions?

Comment: It is possible to teach bash e.g. integer division with floating point results: See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24431665/3776858

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Just double-quote (`"`) the expression:

```
echo "$a / ( $b - 34 )" | bc -l
```

Then bash will expand the `$` variables and ignore everything else and `bc` will see an expression with parentheses:

```
$ a=22
$ b=7
$ echo "$a / ( $b - 34 )" 
22 / ( 7 - 34 )

$ echo "$a / ( $b - 34 )" | bc -l
-.81481481481481481481
```

Comment: Awesome. I never thought of using double quotes to expand the variables. Thank you!

Comment: Mhhh ?  double quotes don't expand the variables but permit that.

Comment: sweet, I would have switched to python if I had stumble upon this.

Comment: It seems I need `-l` for division, but not for addition. Should I simply always use -`l`?

Comment: @user2023370: `-l` uses "mathlib" and also causes the scale to be set to 20 so results will be shown up to 20 decimal places.  Without `-l` the default scale is 0.
See [man bc](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bc)

Comment: @AdrianPronk Yes, I recently found bc's `scale` parameter to help me here. But even thinking about precision also leads to using `-l`, as you will get consistent formatting ... and division works!

Answer (score 13):

Please note that your `echo $(( 22/7 )) | bc -l` actually makes bash calculate 22/7 and then send the result to bc. The integer output is therefore not the result of bc, but simply the input given to bc.

Try `echo $(( 22/7 ))` without piping it to bc, and you'll see.

Answer (score 6):

`scale` variable determines number of digits after decimal separator

```
$ bc
$ scale=2
$ 3/4
$ .75
```

Answer (score 3):

I would prefer awk over bc, it is does the same thing in one command and also gives you more flexibilty to add variables and format your output by using printf:

```
# Define vars in the command
awk -v a=3 -v b=2 'BEGIN{print a/b}'
1.5

# Define vars earlier and init with them awk vars
c=3
d=2
awk -v a=$c -v b=$d 'BEGIN{print a/b}'
1.5

# Use vars that are defined in script
a=3
b=2
awk 'BEGIN{print '$a'/'$b'}'

# Format your output using C printf syntax
awk -v a=3 -v b=2 'BEGIN{printf("%.3f\n", a/b)}'
1.500
```

Also bc does not return a code error if it divides by zero, so you can't check the error:

```
echo 3/0 | bc -l
Runtime error (func=(main), adr=5): Divide by zero
# The error code is zero, that means there is no errors
echo $?
0
```

While awk does return a code error 2:

```
awk -v a=3 -v b=0 'BEGIN{print a/b}'
awk: cmd. line:1: fatal: division by zero attempted
# awk returned code error 2, that indicates that something went wrong
echo $?
2
```

The code error can be used to check for division by zero like:

```
# Set your own vars
if output=$(awk -v a=3 -v b=0 'BEGIN{print a/b}' 2> /dev/null); then
    echo "$output"
else
    echo "error, division by zero"
fi
```

Comment: I agree that `awk` is the best built-in math interpreter in bash. `bash` itself cannot do any floating point `echo $((3/2))`. `bc` cannot handle decimal exponent `echo "2^1.5" | bc -l`. But `awk` can do all of those!

Answer (score 0):

u can handle the div-zero error checking directly at `awk` :

> ```
> for a in 19 29 31; do 
> for b in 11  3  0; do 
>
>    gawk -v PREC=512 -Mbe '$++NF= +(_=$NF) ? $(!!_)/_ : "div_by_zero"' \
>                               \ 
>          CONVFMT='%.59g' OFS=' \t| ' <<< "${a} ${b}"; done; done
> ```

```
19  | 11    | 1.7272727272727272727272727272727272727272727272727272727273
19  | 3     | 6.3333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333
19  | 0     | div_by_zero
29  | 11    | 2.6363636363636363636363636363636363636363636363636363636364
29  | 3     | 9.6666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666667
29  | 0     | div_by_zero
31  | 11    | 2.8181818181818181818181818181818181818181818181818181818182
31  | 3     | 10.333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333
31  | 0     | div_by_zero
```

if u don't need all that `GMP` precision, then `mawk` is willing to directly return an infinity instead of a fatal error message :

> ```
> for a in 19 29 31; do for b in 11 3 0; do 
>
> mawk '$++NF=$++_/$(_+_--)' CONVFMT='%.19g' OFS='\t' <<<"$a $b";done;done
> ```

```
19  11  1.727272727272727293
19  3   6.333333333333333037
19  0   inf
29  11  2.636363636363636243
29  3   9.666666666666666075
29  0   inf
31  11  2.818181818181818343
31  3   10.33333333333333393
31  0   inf
```

or better yet, do it from one single call to `awk` instead of calling it nonstop :

> ```
> for a in 19 29 31; do for b in 11 3 0; do 
>
>     echo "${a} ${b}"
>
> done; done | mawk '$++NF = $(++_) / $(_+_--)' CONVFMT='%.19g' OFS='\t'
> ```

```
19  11  1.727272727272727293
19  3   6.333333333333333037
19  0   inf
29  11  2.636363636363636243
29  3   9.666666666666666075
29  0   inf
31  11  2.818181818181818343
31  3   10.33333333333333393
31  0   inf
```

Or if you so prefer, have `mawk` call `gawk-gmp` indirectly :

> ```
> echo "22 7\n22 4\n22 0" | 
>
> mawk '$++NF = substr(_=__="", (__="gawk -v PREC=65536 -Mbe"\
>               " \47BEGIN { printf(\"%.127f\","(+(_=$(NF-!_))\
>               ? "("($!__)")/("(_)")" : (+(_=$!__)<-_?__:"-") \
>               "log(_<_)")") } \47" ) | getline _, close(__))_'
> ```

```
22 7 3.1428571428571428571428571428571428571428571428571428………
22 4 5.5000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000………
22 0 +inf
```

Answer (score 0):

To expand on the Feb 22, '13 and Sept 1, '22 answers, using `echo` is not required for this, either. You can also use the [*here strings (<<<)*](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html#Here-Strings) to input your data into `bc`.

```
bc -l <<< "$a / ( $b - 34 )"
```

This is useful for making quick one-liners, sometimes.

```
user@machine:~$ a=22; b=7; bc -l <<< "$a / ( $b - 34 )"
-.81481481481481481481
```

`scale` in `bc` can be added to this very easily.

```
user@machine:~$ a=22; b=7; c=2; bc <<< "scale=$c; $a / ( $b - 34 )"
-.81
```

The *here string* is from `bash` and not `bc`, so this works with many other terminal commands, as well.