# Bash and awk to do division

Tags: bash, awk

I am trying to do a simple division computation between two integers that will result in a float.  I do not want to use bc.  This approach works for me for a different purpose with slightly different syntax but I am not quite sure where I am messing up.  I am positive that the variables are getting assigned correctly, but I have an error once I try to do the division, and nothing actually gets assigned to the variable.  Can anyone help?

Thanks in advance!

```
rate=`awk '{ shared = "'"${tempRatioArray[0]}"'"; total = "'"${tempRatioArray[1]}"'";\
        printf "%3.0f\t", shared/total }' | awk '{print}'`
```

Comment: Why don't you want to use 'bc' given that it seems quite suitable ?

Comment: I need to be consistent-- this is code that I am using for my thesis and I am on the tail end!!  We had issues previously with bc properly handling variables so our workaround was awk and so far it has been working as expected!

Comment: Perhaps this is usefull: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24431665/3776858

Answer (score 3):

You can use `bc`:

```
bc -l <<<"scale=3; 5/2"
2.500
```

Adapting to your code:

```
bc -l <<< "scale=3; ${tempRatioArray[0]} / ${tempRatioArray[1]}"
```

Answer (score 2):

That is not correct way of using shell variables in `awk` and you don't need 2 awk commands.

Use it like this:

```
rate=$(awk -v shared="${tempRatioArray[0]}" -v total="${tempRatioArray[1]}" 'BEGIN {
    printf "%.3f", (shared/total) }')
```

Comment: Thank you for the response!  I have tried this:  `rate=`awk -v shared="${tempRatioArray[0]}" -v total="${tempRatioArray[1]}" 'BEGIN { printf "%3.0f\t", (shared/total) }'`` but the rate comes out to equal 0...

Comment: Can you run: `awk -v shared="${tempRatioArray[0]}" -v total=${tempRatioArray[1]}" 'BEGIN {
    printf "[%s][%s]%3.0f\n", shared, total, (shared/total) }'` and tell me its output.

Comment: The output is this: `val for LLC ratio: 5100566
75873367
rate = [5100566][75873367]3.0f
./LLC_resource_migrate.sh: line 204: [: [5100566][75873367]3.0f: integer expression expected`

Comment: Great to know, can you mark the answer as accepted by clicking on tick mark on top-left of my answer.