# Bash how to store a division to a variable

Tags: bash, floating-point, integer, division, bc

I am trying to calculate below formula and store the value to a variable.

The pseudo code should look like:

```
a=10
b=5
c=$(((($a-$b)/52)) | bc -l)
echo $c
```

The result is empty. I couldn't figure out the syntax using `bc`. Please help me use `bc` instead of `awk` or other method.

Comment: also notes that if you need to do **heavy computation** with floating point etc, **bash might not be the tool you should use for this**!!! Each time you call `bc` you create a subprocess (system call user -> kernel mode, fork, exec,... then it takes time with memory allocation, new entry in the processes table, more work for the  process scheduler, cache misses and eventually page misses, dynamic library might be loaded by `bc`,...) so you lose many CPU cycles. This would not be the case if you were using the appropriate language for this!

Comment: See: [Division in script and floating-point](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12147040/3776858)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are *two* things you need to be aware of. The first is that `bc` uses standard input for expressions so you would need to actually *pipe* your expression through it, or use the `<<<` redirection operator, one of:

```
c=$(echo "($a - $b) / 52" | bc)
c=$(bc <<< "($a - $b) / 52")
```

The `<<<` method is specific to `bash` and `ksh` (an *possibly* others, but I'm not really au fait with them). The other method can be used in most shells.

Secondly, you should be careful when using big numbers for this since `bc` has the annoying habit of splitting them across lines:

```
pax$ x=999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999

pax$ echo "$x / 7" | bc
14285714285714285714285714285714285714285714285714285714285714285714\
2
```

In order to avoid this, you need to change the line length:

```
pax$ echo "$x / 7" | BC_LINE_LENGTH=0 bc
142857142857142857142857142857142857142857142857142857142857142857142
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this:

```
a=10
b=5
c=$(bc -l <<< "($a-$b)/52")
echo "$c"
```

```
.09615384615384615384
```

Or by setting a scale of `3`:

```
c=$(bc -l <<< "scale=3; ($a-$b)/52")
echo "$c"
```

```
.096
```

Comment: I picked paxdiablo as his/her answer is more comprehensive. Thanks for the attention!