# Multiple/divide columns in bash

Tags: bash, shell, unix, dataframe, awk

I have a dataframe looking like this:

```
ERR843978.19884 13 51 51
ERR843978.2880 10 49 51
ERR843978.10002 7 48 55
ERR843978.1158 8 45 54
ERR843978.4671 14 62 60
ERR843978.83 15 56 70
ERR843978.9406 8 56 39
ERR843978.8383 12 59 43
ERR843978.8916 6 51 42
```

and I wish to do this for all lines:

```
column2/(column3*column4)
```

and then print out the output in a new file.

I've written a bash script that does it but it's kinda slow, so I'm looking at a more efficient solution (maybe with awk?).

Here's my code

```
while read line
do
        out0=$(awk '{print $1}' <<< $line)
        out1=$(awk '{print $2}' <<< $line)
        out2=$(awk '{print $3}' <<< $line)
        out3=$(awk '{print $4}' <<< $line)
        out4=`echo "scale=5; ($out1 / ($out2 * $out3))"|bc -l`
        echo "$out0;$out4"
done < $file
```

Comment: What if third and fourth columns have zero? Edit to show what’s needed for that

Comment: Btw: Without awk and bc: Use [div function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24431665/3776858) and `while read -r c2 c2 c3 c4; do div $c2 $((c3*c4)); done < file`

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice for why your script is so slow and why to avoid shell loops in general for manipulating text.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, **`awk`** is quite efficient here:

```
awk '{ print $2/($3 * $4) }' file > newfile
```

Comment: You should incorporate `($3!=0 && $4 !=0)` someway even if OP does not state there could possible be values as 0 for a safer way

Comment: I don't have any 0 in my dataframe but I tested his solution and 0's will not crash the command, you just get "inf" as output so it's fine by me

Comment: How would you incorporate this @Inian?

Comment: @Stenemo: I would do `awk '$3 !=0 || $4 !=0 { print $2/($3 * $4) }'`

Answer (score 1):

If you split the line with `read` (as @Cyrus suggested, but without the `div`)

```
while read -r column1 column2 column3 column4
do
    echo "bc: $column1;$( echo "scale=5; ($column2 / ($column3 * $column4))"|bc )"
done < $file
```

it would be a bit faster.   On my machine 6sec/1000 rows vs. 1.7sec/1000 rows.

With a combination of `sed`, `bc` and `paste`

```
{
  echo "scale=5;"
  sed -re 's/(.*) ([0-9]+) ([0-9]+) ([0-9]+)/\2 \/ ( \3 * \4 )/' $file
} | bc > $$.tmp
cut -d ' ' -f 1 $file | paste - $$.tmp
```

it has been done in 1.1sec/100000 rows. That is a factor of ~150 and explains, why while-loop has a bad reputation.

Using ksh93, which allows Floating-point arithmetic you reach similar numbers.

```
typeset -F5 column2 column3 column4
while read -r column1 column2 column3 column4
do
    printf "printf %s;%.5f\n" "$column1 " "$(( column2 / (column3 * column4) ))"
done < $file
```

0.9sec/100,000 rows. This reveals, it is not the loop itself, but using an external command `bc` within the loop.

And yes, awk is still ~8 times faster, 1.4 sec/1,000,000 rows